# Sorting a vector<const char *>

Tags: c++, vector, const-char

```
for ( fs::directory_iterator dir_itr2( out_folder ); dir_itr2 != end_iter; ++dir_itr2 )
{
    cout << "Path del file da inserire nel vettore:" << dir_itr2->path().string().c_str() << endl;
    final_path.push_back(dir_itr2->path().string().c_str());


}

sort( final_path.begin(), final_path.end() );
cout << "Vettore di path da aprire in ordine" << endl;
for(vector<const char *>::iterator fp_itr2=final_path.begin(); fp_itr2!=final_path.end(); ++fp_itr2)
{       
    cout << "Path: " << *fp_itr2 << endl;
}
```

Here I tried to put my path in a vector beacuse i need ordinated list, but the cout's output is this:

```
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180426163618363.txt
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180426163654027.txt
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180530150135770.txt
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180426163414599.txt
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180530150235481.txt
Path del file da inserire nel vettore:/srv/FD/super_tracker/tracks/180530150132796.txt
Path: 
Path: 
Path: 
Path: 
Path: 
Path:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using temporaries and dangling pointers that way is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: just dont use `const char*` or `.c_str()` unless you absolutely need to. Use strings

Comment: To store paths in a vector, I would use `vector<path>` :-)  No tricks. And anyway, when you `sort()` pointers they get sorted in address order, not in alphabetical order from what they point to.

Comment: Thanks to all, I think I will take the "string metod".

Answer (score 3):

As the comments say, don't use `char*`. Second, you should use a debugger.

The reason your `sort()` fails is that you are sorting the pointers, according to the location in memory they point to, instead of using the characters pointed to.

You could use a predicate to tell `sort()` how to sort your objects:

```
sort(begin(final_path), end(final_path), 
    [](const char* a, const char *b) { return strcmp(a, b) < 0; }
);
```

But the best course is definitely to use `string` or directly `path` as the type of the vector elements.

Comment: It cannot work, `dir_itr2->path().string()` member `string()` of `path` object returns object *by value* not by reference, so temporary object is created and after calling `c_str` you have dangling pointer ...